# No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present using angular + WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, angular6, woocommerce-rest-api

[image]when i post the data using POST method in woocommerce api.  i am getting cors issue

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/wordpress/wc-api/v3/customers?oauth_consumer_key=ck_64d88e1fa3516e9f5a06b6053f02976a534d3f8f&oauth_nonce=zsu3ysEnFHhvrZt4Nc7H66Dgu28H20K7&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1562587817&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=KtFxvyQNklUlfCi6rNWyJ0DEJ6AS2ZbwbO44u%2FEqxG4%3D' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on each request to the server, if your server is on a different domain than the app on which you are making those requests (the server sets it as a response header). Adding that header tells the system that the external domain "localhost:8100" is allowed to make those requests.

You cannot circumvent this requirement in vanilla browsers, because it is a built in security feature to reduce CORS attacks

PS. different ports on the same domain are considered to be different domains. Thus example.com will get a 401 error, if you are making a request to example.com:8100. Same goes for localhost, or any other domain.

Example code from an Apache2 web server .conf file, that I personally use to set these headers.

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(staging.\xxx\.com|xxx\.com|xxx\.local|xxx\.local:4200|a2\.local)$" origin_is=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
```

Just replace the xxx.com domains with localhost:8100 or whatever else you need in that array. (if you are using Apache web server)

As a result, the Chrome network tab should have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on attached to the request

[image]